# Ошибка при выводе данных из БД

Tags: python, sqlite

Работаю с SQLite. Есть таблица с данными админов: `fisrtname`, `lastname`, `chatid`.
Одновременно работаю с VkApi (Пишу бота).

Вот основной код:

```
def listAdmins():

    import sqlite3

    Connect = sqlite3.connect("CaptureBotDB.db")
    Cursor = Connect.cursor()

    mess = 'Список админов беседы:\n\n'
    chat_id_ = event.chat_id

    sql = """SELECT fname, lname, uid FROM AdminsFromChats WHERE cid = ?"""
    Cursor.execute(sql, (str(chat_id_),))

    for num, (first, last, user_id) in enumerate(Cursor.fetchall(), 1):

        mess += f"{num}.\t{first}\t{last}" + '\n'

    vk.messages.send(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=mess,
        random_id = 0
    )
```

При запросе возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Степан/Desktop/VkBot/main.py", line 1006, in <module>
    listAdmins()
  File "c:/Users/Степан/Desktop/VkBot/main.py", line 117, in listAdmins
    Cursor.execute(sql, (str(chat_id_),))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: AdminsFromChats
```

Сначала подумал, что просто нету данных в таблице, считает так его сказать - пустым. Написал данные вручную, но саравно не помогло. Потом перевёл и понял, что он не видит таблицу: `sqlite3.OperationalError: нет такой таблицы: AdminsFromChats.`

Подскажите, что не так.

Comment: "Что не так?" - таблица "AdminsFromChats" отсутствует в файле "CaptureBotDB.db"

Comment: @MaxU, https://imgur.com/FfyPIY8

Comment: @MaxU, Затея в, что всё есть.

Comment: вы уверены, что открываете именно этот файл? может у вас в другой директории файл с тем же именем? Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу...